# Is there a way to silence the error "isn't precompiled"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets, precompile

I have a rails app where I precompile my assets and send them to a remote AWS S3 bucket. 
I would like to add my public/assets folder to my gitignore because it is starting to be pretty large and I don't want git saving all changed to the compiled files. But if I do rails complains that it is not finding the precompiled files and basically crashes the whole app.

Is there a way around this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try to ignore public and set `config.assets.enabled = false`